# Apple Mail is listing my email account only in conversations. (Gmail Address)

Tags: email, gmail, apple-mail

I use Apple Mail to read my Gmail.

It's just started labeling all of my conversations with solely my Email Account.

When you click on the conversation that's 3 or more emails long. 
It's maintaining my initial email.
It's filtering out the response from the Other Person.
It's summarizing the response from the Other Person in my response to the response.
It's labeled the conversation with only my Email Account in the summary.

This started happening this weekend or today.

Is this a common problem?